# Using attribute Id how to get attribute label in magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, product-attribute

Using attribute Id how to get attribute label in magento 2.1.
example :

```
    Array
       (
         [93] => 30
         [188] => 26
         [189] => 15
        ).
```

Answer (score 1):

> Use below code:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_eavConfig = $eavConfig;
}


$attributeObj = $this->_eavConfig->getAttribute($entityType, $code);
$attributeObj->getFrontendLabel();
```

For example:

```
$attributeObj = $this->_eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', 30);
$attributeObj->getFrontendLabel();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$_product = $this->objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);

$attributes = $product->getAttributes();

foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
     label => __($attribute->getStoreLabel()),
     'value' => $value, //attribute Value
     'code' => $attribute->getAttributeCode(), //attribute Code
}
```

If looking for Option Text from OptionId:

```
$optionId = 30;
$attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('design_color');
if ($attribute->usesSource()) {
    $optionText = $attribute->getSource()->getOptionText($optionId);
}
```

If looking for attribute Label from attribute Code:

```
$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('your_attribute_code')->getFrontend()->getText($_product);
```

> > NOTE: Inject objectManager from contructor, Direct Use of ObjectManager is not allowed as per Magento

Comment: hi @Ronak my attribute id=93 so how to get attribute label?

Answer (score 0):

> Try to use bellow code

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Modulename\Helper;

/**
* Class Helper Data
*
* @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
*/
class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    protected $eavConfig;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig
    ){
        $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
    }

    // pass Attribute Code and Option Value
    public function getAttributeOptionLabel($attributeCode, $optionValue){
        $attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', $attributeCode);
        $options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
        $key = array_search($optionValue, array_column($options, 'value'));
        return strtolower($options[$key]['label']); 
    }
}
```